# HTML/JS end of line punctuation wrongly aligns to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, punctuation

I encountered a strange display of punctuation within DIV elements. In my HTML the text is something like:

```
This is just some
random text...!!
```

But in the browser window, it systematically becomes:

```
This is just some
!!...random text
```

I am using the code from [IntroJS](http://introjs.com/docs/), and I wonder if this has to do with default formatting of [right-to-left languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) (such as Persian or Arabic). I am guessing this because also trying to select the text from the DIV only works when clicking top right to bottom left.

Point is, I don't know how to remove this formatting or setting in order for punctuation to display correctly in English.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Please show us some mark-up - otherwise it's the glassball on the table.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some RTL text mixed in there. We can't help you without an actual example. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if any of your CSS has `direction: rtl`. If your intention is not to support RTL, then removing this should fix the problem.

If you do need to support it, then I recommend this excellent (but long!) article: http://moriel.smarterthanthat.com/tips/the-language-double-take-dealing-with-bidirectional-text-or-wait-tahw/

TLDR: the reason your punctuation changes order is due to the *weak directionality* of certain characters... and it's a right PITA when dealing with multilingual sites that mix LTR and RTL!

Comment: Thank you, indeed IntroJS provided two CSS files, one of which specified the "RTL" direction. I blindly loaded this secondary CSS file without knowing its exact purpose. By removing it from my HTML page altogether fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing this out!